# wss websocket over nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, websocket, wss

Could someone help me? I have java app with websocket server. It works by ws. I need to add ssl in nginx. I added two config: one for proxy by ws and another for wss

```
        server {

            listen 15459;


            location / {

                    proxy_pass http://localhost:15259;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
            }

    }

    server {
            listen 15359 ssl;

            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/topaz_wss.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/topaz_wss.key;

            ssl_protocols       TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_session_timeout 5m;


            location / {

                    proxy_pass http://localhost:15259;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
            }

    }
```

So, If I connect by ws to 15359 , everything is ok. But, when I connect to 15459 by wss, it dose not work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: *" it dose not work."* - "Does not work" is not helpful as the only error description. Please provide the exact errors you get in the developer tools. Also check the server access and error logs for details.

Comment: how do you connect? does the client trust your CA or certificate?